# Standalone Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is there way to use standalone Qt Creator just to make *.ui files? I mean without full Qt installation, which is 3+Gb on disk. Qt Creator exists on qt-project in standalone form, but there is no possibility to create a project.

Comment: You actually only need Qt Designer (Qt Creator embeds this among other tools). But I am not sure you can install it without the Qt SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator creates *.ui files.

Just go to File->New->New File or Project...->Files and Classes->Qt->Qt Designer Form.

Please read more [Developing Widget Based Applications](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-using-qt-designer.html) and [Qt Designer Manual](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/designer-manual.html).

Comment: Yeah, sounds strange, but there is no "Qt Designer Form" in the list ("Qt Resource file", "QML File (Qt Quick 1)", "QML File (Qt Quick 2)" and "JS file" only). I'm using Qt Creator downloaded from [link](http://qt-project.org/downloads) (Qt Creator 2.6.2 for Windows (51 MB)). But when i'm using "full" package (Qt 5.0.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7, 823 MB)) evertything is fine, but i don't need all this stuff. So, question are still opened.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator can be downloaded as standalone file from the offline installers page:
https://www.qt.io/offline-installers